# regexec did not return all expected matches

Tags: java, c++, c, regex, posix

I'm running into a problem wherein my regexec code is returning differently from my Java code. I used the same regular expression but returns differently in c++/c.

Here's my code snippet:

```
const char *pattern = "(%\\(.*?\\)|\\%[ds])";
if ((ret = regcomp(&regEx, pattern, REG_EXTENDED )) != 0)
    printf ("%d error on regex..\n", ret);

while (1)
{
    if(regexec(&regEx, cursor, maxGroups, grpArray, REG_NOTBOL)){
        break;  // No more matches
    }

    unsigned int g = 0;
    unsigned int offset = 0;
    for (g = 0; g < 1; g++)
    {
      if (grpArray[g].rm_so == (size_t)-1)
      {
        break;  // No more groups
      }

        char result[strlen(src) + 1];
        if (g == 0)
            offset = grpArray[g].rm_eo;
        char cursorCopy[strlen(cursor) + 1];
        strcpy(cursorCopy, cursor);
        cursorCopy[grpArray[g].rm_eo] = 0;
        parseFormatSpecifier(strResult);
        g++;
    }
    cursor += offset;
    //memset(&grpArray[0], 0, sizeof(grpArray));
}
regfree(&regEx);
```

Actual return data (C/C++):

- result: %(04up16)-%(02up8)-%(02up8) %(02up8):%(02up8)%(ip16) (0)
- result: %(04up16)-%(02up8)-%(02up8) %(02up8):%(02up8)%(ip16) (1)

Expected (Java):

- result: %(04up16)-%(02up8)-%(02up8) %(02up8):%(02up8)%(ip16)
- result: %(04up16)
- result: %(02up8)
- result: %(02up8)
- result: %(02up8)
- result: %(02up8)
- result: %(ip16)

changing the pattern to:

```
        const char *pattern = (\\%\\(.*?\\)|\\%[ds]);
```

returns differently:

- result: %(04up16)-%(02up8)-%(02up8) %(02up8):%(02up8)%(ip16) - 0
- result: %(04up16)-%(02up8)-%(02up8) %(02up8):%(02up8)%(ip16) - 1

By the way, using both patterns/regular expressions in java is returning fine. Meaning it returns all matches correctly. Is there something wrong with my regular expression? Anyone can help me how to construct the regular expression for posix to have the expected results below? % should be followed by '(' then followed by any character and closed by a ')' or % should be followed by an 's' or 'd'.

Examples to be accepted by the regular expression:

- %d %s %(02up8) %(ip16) %(d32) %(X8)

Comment: I mean, i have the same regular expression used in my other java code but it worked fine. with my c++ code, it returned differently.

Comment: Then can you at least show the Java code you use?

Comment: Unfortunately, regular expression come in many flavours. Maybe the extended regexes of the POSIX regex lib don't recognize the non-greedy operator `*?`.

Comment: @MOehm is right, POSIX ERE doesn't support non-greedy quantifiers.  Try this instead: `"(%\\([^()]*\\)|\\%[ds])"`

Answer (score 0):

Try to stare at the following line in your code, for a minute or two, and see if you can figure out the answer yourself:

```
for (g = 0; g < 1; g++)
```

P.S. In addition to incrementing `g` in the for-loop itself, you're also incrementing it in the body of the loop as well. So, this won't work for several reasons.

Comment: My bad, this is a typo. the additional g++ shoud be removed.